# Use PRIMARY EVENT OBJECT Id in ampscript didn't work for SMS template

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

Here is my example code to retrive the record Id of the primary event object in a journey.

```
SET @CpId = Coupon__c:Id
```

Coupon__c is a custom object in salesforce. 
Now this works for Email templates but not on SMS templates.

Can anyone tell me how you can retrieve a Id and fields of the record entered in the journey?

Answer (score 1):

MobileConnect SMS content can only include data from the Mobile Demographics table apparently. It cannot retrieve data from Syncronised Data Extensions even if they are correctly linked in Contact Builder.

Comment: @sur - were you able to solve this ? If so, how ?